# whats the best way to add custom header on top with target blank

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am openning a new window like this

```
<a href="mysite.com"  target="_blank">open window</a>
```

but in the new window, on top I wanna show my companys header and the logo. How can tht be done.

thanks

Comment: You go to mysite.com and add the company's header and logo?

Comment: or what Sean3z suggested.. I didn't quite get what you were after at first.  I was thinking mysite.com was a page you controlled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably be best to open a new page containing your header and an iFrame of the site you're trying to display.